# Serious Issue after Neo4jClient Upgrade

Tags: c#, asp.net, neo4j, asp.net-membership, neo4jclient

I have asked a couple of questions over the last few days and got some great answers, then main solution seemed to be to upgrade my client to the latest version, I have been hesitant because of this reason.

C# Solution contains:

An ASP.NET Web Forms application which doesn't have a reference to the Neo4JClient, it's just a service front end.

A class library which uses the newest version of the client (dll says v1.1.0.0), this is the project the WebForms project uses for data.

A BasicAuthHTTPModule which uses the newer version of the client.

A Neo4jClient source library (no idea what version, and don't know how to check) which is used by the MembershipProvider project below.

A Neo4jMembershipProvider which uses the above Neo4jClient dll as a reference.

They were all using the older version until earlier today when I did a selective upgrade of BasicAuth, and the Class Library, now the solution builds as expected but when you launch it in the browser you get:

```
Method not found: 'Void Neo4jClient.GraphClient..ctor(System.Uri)'. 

Source Error:
Line 48:       <providers>
Line 49:         <clear />
Line 50:         <add name="Neo4JRoleProvider" type="Nextwave.Neo4J.Membership.Neo4JRolesProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
Line 51:       </providers>
Line 52:     </roleManager>
```

Now, this is a serious error for me, we need to upgrade, but I can't find anything about this error. I am aware however that there were big changes to the client recently, so any pointers would be great.

Thanks

UPDATE: I updated the Neo4jMembershipProvider to the newer client version too, just so we are all running on the same code, but on build it comes back with this:

```
'Nextwave.Neo4J.Membership.Data.User' does not contain a definition for 'Data' and no extension method 'Data' accepting a first argument of type 'Nextwave.Neo4J.Membership.Data.User'
```

Caused by: u.FirstOrDefault().Data.Username

Comment: We are going to move over to ASP.NET Identity, but at this point we cannot make a change that big to a system this large in the timeframe we have before launch.

Comment: Oh, although it won't really matter we're not even getting to the communication stage, the server version of Neo4J is 2.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed Data from the 2 lines in question (from RoleProvider.cs in Neo4JMembershipProvider and everything compiled and worked perfectly.

```
u.FirstOrDefault().Data.Username --> u.FirstOrDefault().Username

roleList.Add(r.FirstOrDefault().Data.RoleName); --> roleList.Add(r.FirstOrDefault().RoleName);
```

Comment: Just adding for clarity. In versions 1.0.x of Neo4jClient - the `CollectAs<T>` statement returned `IEnumerable<Node<T>>` (with the `Data` property) - 1.1.x changed that to just return `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Yeah, I had to edit about 200 classes to remove the extra <Node, if you recall I posted a question a few weeks ago regarding this and ended up writing some extra code to return xml, it was cannot serialize because <x> is an interface :/